# How can I clone a matrix view into an owned vector with nalgebra?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

```rust
pub type VecD = OVector<i32, Dyn>;

let a = VecD::from_vec(vec![0, 1, 2, 3]);
let b = a.view((0, 0), (2, 1)).clone_owned();
```

this works and I get `b` with `Matrix<i32, Dyn, Dyn, VecStorage<i32, Dyn, Dyn>>` type.

In contrast,

```rust
let b: VecD = a.view((0, 0), (2, 1)).clone_owned();
```

does not work and throws:

```
Type mismatch [E0308] expected `VecD`, but found `OMatrix<i32, Dyn, Dyn>`
```

How can I clone the matrix view into `Matrix<i32, Dyn, Const<1>, VecStorage<i32, Dyn, Const<1>>>` type?

Comment: Isn't the difference between the snippets only that you specify the type annotation?

Comment: Yes, but the last snippet results in an error that I don't know how to fix elegantly.
How can I cast it correctly?

Comment: Well, if it's a `Matrix`, then it's definitely not an `OVector`. What did you expect?

Comment: I want to cast it into an `OVector<i32, Dyn>` and don't know what's the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`generic_view()`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.generic_view) is what you want:

```rust
let b = a.generic_view((0, 0), (Dyn(2), Const::<1>)).clone_owned();
```